# How to create new vector in each iteration?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

When I run the code below, in my `trainingVector` I get:

```
{(10,0),(10,0),(10,0)...}
```

instead of:

```
{(0,0),(1,0),(2,0)...}
```

How do i make this work correctly?

```
vector< vector< double > * > trainingVector; 
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){     
    vector<double> ok (2,0);
    ok[0]=i;
    trainingVector.push_back(&ok)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are using right now won't work because the life of each vector `ok` object lasts only within the iteration before it falls out of scope and dies.

You need to do this instead:

```
vector< vector< double > * > trainingVector; 
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){     
   vector<double> *ok = new vector<double>(2,0);
   (*ok)[0]=i;
   trainingVector.push_back(ok);
}
```

Be aware that you will need to free each inner vector manually later. Or you'll get a memory leak.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){     
   delete trainingVector[i];
}
```

Alternatively, you can do it without pointers all together:

```
vector< vector< double > > trainingVector; 
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){     
   vector<double> ok(2,0);
   ok[0]=i;
   trainingVector.push_back(ok);
}
```

Though this latter method implies copying the inner vector when it is put into the outer vector.

Comment: If the life of each vector lasts only within the iteration, he wouldn't be getting the output of all ten pushed on references, just the last one or none depending on when he checks the parent vector. The issue is that he is not creating a new vector each time, but referencing the same one (same memory location, which is on the stack)

Comment: Actually, what he's seeing (referencing the same one) is just the result of the undefined behavior that he has caused by accessing something that has fallen out of scope.

Comment: @Wizetux: *wrong*. The code is creating a *new* vector each time, and each vector lasts only within the iteration. Dereferencing the pointer later on is undefined behaviour, and everything is possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The first thing is exactly what I needed. I cannot use the second one, since my trainingVector must have pointers in it...

Comment: @Wizetux whether it is the same memory location or not, it doesn't change the fact that the lifetime of each `vector` on the stack is a single iteration of the loop.

Comment: Okay, maybe it doesnt have to. Its just that im also putting ok in a map. And want to make sure that when it gets changed in the map it also gets changed in trainingVector. Below Martinho commented that i can use & instead. So I will try if something goes wrong.

Comment: @Mysticial Can you please explain the construct vector(2,0) used as an rvalue(in the third example you gave). I have never seen such usage before and this intrigued me. I understand that It creates a vector of size 2 and filled with zeros and returns a reference to it and these will be copied to the vector ok. Can you provide a reference for such an usage?

Comment: @router It's constructor #2 here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

Comment: @Mysticial Whats the difference in creating a vector using vector<double> ok(2, 0) and vector<double> ok = vector(2,0). Is the latter case similar to creating an object on the heap whereas the former one is on the call stack? Shouldn't the code provided by the OP result in Undefined behaviour?

Comment: @Mysticial I think we should mention the template type in the third example you gave or else it gives a compilation error. vector<double> ok = vector<double>(2,0);

Comment: @router 1) There's no difference. Once constructs, the other constructs and assigns which is elided away. The OP's code is indeed UB which is probably this question existed in the first place. 2) That was an oversight when I wrote the answer. Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Just don't use pointers.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> trainingVector;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    std::vector<double> ok(2, 0);
    ok[0] = i;
    trainingVector.push_back(ok);
}
```

Also consider using [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html) instead.

Comment: Hey, cat, I must use pointers... Mysticals answer worked for me.

Comment: because the elements of the trainingVector - i need to modify them without calling trainingVector

Comment: @sks: That doesn't mean you need to store pointers (which will require you to `delete` them later). You can use references or even get a pointer to an existing vector later on with `&trainingVector[0]` (and that won't need deletion, because the vector takes care of it).

Comment: Hmm, I will try that... If something breaks down :)

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel not you too :( I hope you are lying to children.

Comment: Its just that im also putting ok in a map. And want to make sure that when it gets changed in the map it also gets changed in trainingVector.